# Create two almost identical arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to create two very alike arrays. The second array only has one more item then the first one...

So what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
$array_one = ('one', 'two', 'three');
$array_two = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');
```

Is there a function to do so? I've looked at things like `array_push`, `array_shift`, but those aren't functions meant to do this kind of behavior I think.

Any build in function to "push" one item on a copy of an array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with:

```
$array_two = array_merge($array_one, array('four'));
```

or

```
$array_two   = $array_one;
$array_two[] = 'four';
```

or

```
$array_two = $array_one;
array_push($array_two, 'four');
```

or

```
$array_two = $array_one + array('four');
```

or

```
$array_two  = $array_one;
$array_two += array('four');
```

Comment: More then enough options I see! Thanks!

Comment: Ofc, but time wasn't there to accept it yet! But it's done :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Michiel what you want more in this answer, it is good as par your question.

Answer (score 7):

You can try

```
print_r($array_one + $array_two);
```

This will just add extra value.